# Chrome won't save my passwords even after prompting me

Tags: google-chrome

So I've been having some problems with Chrome. I installed it on a fresh install of windows 7 and it has been giving me problems when I ask it to save my passwords.

So it happens like this, I go to a page, say like reddit, and I enter my username and password. Everything is fine and I log in, and then Chrome prompts me to save my password. I click save, but when I go to the "manage passwords" section in settings, it shows no saved passwords.

If I restart my computer and get back into chrome, no passwords are saved and it has me log back into chrome before showing my saved settings (a yellow triangle appears where my name is in the top-right corner and upon clicking, prompts me to enter my password).

Any help would be appreciated, I generally love chrome and I don't want to use another browser, but I don't want to deal with this crap.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?p=settings_password&rd=1

Comment: Yeah, I've been there. I've enabled autofill and offer to save your passwords. I'm not having a problem with it offering to save them, I'm having a problem with it actually saving them.